# own http4 Camel Component with own URI

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to create my own Camel Component. Based on the Component http4. I want only insert server and port by default. So i can write:

```
from("myhttp://test1.php")
 .to("myhttp://test2.php")
```

And my Component change the URI to "http:// myhost:8080/test1.php" and "http:// myhost:8080/test2.php" but I can't create my own scheme Name. I test @UriEndpoint(scheme = "myhttp") in the class

```
public class myhttpEndpoint extends org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpEndpoint {
}
```

Can you help me?

What I do:

```
public class myhttpComponent extends org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpComponent {

    @Override
    protected Endpoint createEndpoint(String uri, String remaining, Map<String, Object> parameters) throws Exception {
    ...
    ...
    HttpEndpoint endpoint = new myhttpEndpoint(endpointUriString, this, clientBuilder, localConnectionManager, configurer);
    ...
    ...
    }
}

@UriEndpoint(scheme = "myhttp")
public class myhttpEndpoint extends org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpEndpoint {

    public myhttpEndpoint(String endpointUriString,
            cacheComponent cacheComponent, HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder,
            HttpClientConnectionManager localConnectionManager,
            HttpClientConfigurer configurer) throws URISyntaxException {
        super(endpointUriString, cacheComponent, clientBuilder, localConnectionManager, configurer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @UriEndpoint annotation is actually optional when creating a custom Camel component and I think it's only used if you want configuration documentation to be automatically generated. More info: http://camel.apache.org/endpoint-annotations.html

To tie your component class to the component name "myhttp", you need to add a file under the `META-INF` folder in your project. More details: http://camel.apache.org/writing-components.html